# mutate_all using map and case_when / ifelse on lists in r

Tags: r

My data looks something similar to the following:

```
$`2013 Jul`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
      AAPL     AMD      ADI    ABBV        A      APD       AA       CF     NVDA      HOG      WMT     AMZN
     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 -0.00252 0.00385 0.000314 0.00148 0.000231 0.000644 -0.00107 -0.00137 0.000886 0.000806 0.000689 0.000615
2  1       5       2        5       2        3         1        1       4        4        3        3       

$`2013 Aug`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
       AAPL     AMD     ADI    ABBV         A     APD        AA       CF    NVDA      HOG      WMT    AMZN
      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 0.0000471 0.00297 0.00111 0.00187 0.0000542 0.00186 -0.000795 -0.00109 0.00140 0.000700 0.000965 0.00101
2 1         5       3       5       2         4        1         1       4       2        3        3
```

I am trying to use `case_when` in a `dplyr`, `mutate` and `map` function over a list of `tibble`s. Where I replace all lists which contain a 5 or a 1 with a 0.5 and all else with a 0.

I am trying a variation of `mutate_all` but do not know how to use `case_when` with `mutate_all`. I am open to other suggestions on how to solve this also.

```
x[1] %>% 
  mutate_all(case_when(... = 5 ~ 0.5))
```

Data

```
list(`2013 Jul` = structure(list(AAPL = c(-0.00252413896048252, 
1), AMD = c(0.00385385230384388, 5), ADI = c(0.000313658814841043, 
2), ABBV = c(0.00148473194650269, 5), A = c(0.000231372267065186, 
2), APD = c(0.000644411609229898, 3), AA = c(-0.00106999405402468, 
1), CF = c(-0.00136811540143579, 1), NVDA = c(0.000886436095375894, 
4), HOG = c(0.000806051331850114, 4), WMT = c(0.000689490484865284, 
3), AMZN = c(0.000614708184565435, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2013 Aug` = structure(list(
    AAPL = c(0.0000471064768722691, 1), AMD = c(0.00297250845145986, 
    5), ADI = c(0.00110927645875706, 3), ABBV = c(0.00186505842086247, 
    5), A = c(0.0000542259939665846, 2), APD = c(0.00186178155179209, 
    4), AA = c(-0.000794925865044543, 1), CF = c(-0.00109320436559941, 
    1), NVDA = c(0.00139874293303574, 4), HOG = c(0.000699507074667968, 
    2), WMT = c(0.000964557826996342, 3), AMZN = c(0.00100980845937234, 
    3)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), `2013 Sep` = structure(list(AAPL = c(0.000874550640770086, 
3), AMD = c(0.00212896308150426, 5), ADI = c(0.000297401899798995, 
1), ABBV = c(0.00126327568847214, 4), A = c(0.00097767693668047, 
3), APD = c(0.00143416399096666, 5), AA = c(-0.000734440361937234, 
1), CF = c(-0.000254998800234454, 1), NVDA = c(0.00127259109916125, 
4), HOG = c(0.00105093597431519, 3), WMT = c(0.00038339075327491, 
2), AMZN = c(0.000479002073488143, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2013 Oct` = structure(list(
    AAPL = c(0.000682565466572836, 2), AMD = c(0.00313699867162714, 
    5), ADI = c(0.000209923665516306, 1), ABBV = c(0.000865756791407934, 
    2), A = c(0.00161631482825611, 4), APD = c(0.00168294315897343, 
    5), AA = c(-0.000319519044240903, 1), CF = c(0.00096163857613333, 
    3), NVDA = c(0.00158604314072248, 4), HOG = c(0.00151424115101764, 
    3), WMT = c(0.00000265229900199134, 1), AMZN = c(0.00124777917896926, 
    3)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), `2013 Nov` = structure(list(AAPL = c(0.00138847413611967, 
4), AMD = c(0.00131189086851618, 3), ADI = c(0.000998905149605624, 
2), ABBV = c(0.00053428429850944, 1), A = c(0.0016278252466143, 
4), APD = c(0.0018596391559994, 5), AA = c(0.000727945791304539, 
1), CF = c(0.00128641077503917, 3), NVDA = c(0.000839077531026809, 
2), HOG = c(0.00128443125529569, 3), WMT = c(-0.00000406995915300601, 
1), AMZN = c(0.00279573900270221, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), `2013 Dec` = structure(list(AAPL = c(0.00176889092052374, 
5), AMD = c(-0.000742603775364103, 1), ADI = c(0.00044132637464973, 
1), ABBV = c(0.00113925715965696, 3), A = c(0.00135042334177499, 
4), APD = c(0.00122867453428789, 3), AA = c(0.00102055404174894, 
2), CF = c(0.00128611035428346, 3), NVDA = c(0.000674203471055744, 
2), HOG = c(0.00164877495332821, 4), WMT = c(0.000671450466059644, 
1), AMZN = c(0.00299158521138261, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

EDIT:

Is it possible to make sure the numbers sum to 1? For example, currently we have:

```
$`2017 Aug`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0   0       0     0     0     0   0     0     0     0       0     0
2     0   0.5     0     0     0     0   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5     0
```

Which is correct. However I now see that there are four `0-5`'s. Is it possible to get the output as:

```
 $`2017 Aug`
    # A tibble: 2 x 12
       AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     0   0       0     0     0     0   0     0     0     0       0     0
    2     0   0.20     0     0     0     0   0.20   0.20   0.20   0.20     0     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a `list`, we can loop through the `list`

```
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
                mutate_all(~ case_when(. %in% c(5, 1) ~ .5, 
                                        TRUE ~ 0)) )
```

Also, in this case, we can do this without `case_when` as well

```
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
               mutate_all( ~ c(0, .5)[(. %in% c(5, 1)) + 1]))
```

---

If we need to make the columns sum to 1, one option is to subtract the first number from 1 for those cases which doesn't `sum` to 1 (as there are only two rows)

```
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
            mutate_all(~ case_when(. %in% c(5, 1) ~ .5, 
                                    TRUE ~ 0) ) %>% 
            mutate_all(~ if(sum(.) != 1) replace(., 1, 1 - sum(.)) else .)  )
```

---

Or if we need to normalize the rows

```
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
            mutate_all(~ case_when(. %in% c(5, 1) ~ .5, 
                                    TRUE ~ 0) ) %>%
         pmap_dfr(., ~ 
                  {v1 <- c(...)
                   v2 <- if(sum(v1) > 1) replace(v1, v1 != 0, 1/sum(v1!=0)) else v1
                   as.list(v2)}))
#$`2013 Jul`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
#   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0     0       0   0       0     0   0     0       0     0     0     0
#2   0.2   0.2     0   0.2     0     0   0.2   0.2     0     0     0     0

#$`2013 Aug`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
#   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0     0       0   0       0     0   0     0       0     0     0     0
#2   0.2   0.2     0   0.2     0     0   0.2   0.2     0     0     0     0

#$`2013 Sep`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
#   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0   0     0       0     0   0     0     0       0     0     0     0
#2     0   0.2   0.2     0     0   0.2   0.2   0.2     0     0     0     0

#$`2013 Oct`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
#   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0   0     0       0     0   0     0       0     0     0   0       0
#2     0   0.2   0.2     0     0   0.2   0.2     0     0     0   0.2     0

$`2013 Nov`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0   0       0   0     0       0     0     0   0     0  
2     0     0     0   0.2     0   0.2   0.2     0     0     0   0.2   0.2

$`2013 Dec`
# A tibble: 2 x 12
   AAPL   AMD   ADI  ABBV     A   APD    AA    CF  NVDA   HOG   WMT  AMZN
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0     0     0       0     0     0     0     0     0     0   0     0  
2   0.2   0.2   0.2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   0.2   0.2
```

Comment: An additional comment I just realised. Is there a way to make the case_when or ~c(0, 0.5)  sum to 1. I add an edit to the original post to demonstrate a little better

Comment: @user8959427  That logic is not clear after the replacement.  i.e. is it for a column or row?

Comment: I would like to do it for the row.

Comment: The rows are supposed to be "weights" than can never be greater than 1. So if `AA` == 1 and `CF` == 1 and `AAPL` == 5 and `NVDA`== 5 then they should get 0.25 each.